# Cannot access static resources Asp.Net Mvc 2 on IIS 7. when configured a Virtual Host

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Cannot access static resources Asp.Net Mvc 2 on IIS 7. when configured a Virtual Host.

I've set the following:

1. In hosts.etc I've written the following "127.0.0.1 localhost blueprint"
2. I've create in IIS 7 set the directory root to where the MVC 2 application is located and set the domain host name to blueprint over http and port 80.

I can open the site normally by going to http://blueprint , all MVC 2 functionalities work fine.

But the CSS won't load, everytime the system returns the error 404 status for a resource not found.

The css file is located in here /Views/Shared/screen.css .

I've tried the following to get a proper path:

Url.Content("~/Views/Shared/screen.css")
Url.Content("/Views/Shared/screen.css")
Url.Content("Views/Shared/screen.css")

Or just
"~/Views/Shared/screen.css"
"/Views/Shared/screen.css"
"Views/Shared/screen.css"

or

"screen.css".

The css file is requested from a master page located in the same directory as the screen.css file , Views/Shared/master.master .

Comment: Can you post the actual code you have in your view to render the css tag. Also, just a hunch but try putting it outside the views directory... put it in a root `styles` directory or something.

Comment: Is there a reason why are you not placing it in the Content folder where styles and images go by default?

Comment: Ignorance, I guess. I've just started learning Asp.net mvc 2 and don't know all the ropes yet. Will try your suggestions and report on  the success soon.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this not 5 minutes ago. I fixed it by going into "Turn Windows Features On or off" in the control panel then "Internet Information Services" "World Wide Web Services" and make sure "Static Content" is checked.